# access web.config using wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, web-config

Would anyone be so kind as to help me figure out how to open a web.config file from a wpf thick client. I have a wpf form (not a silverlight app) that I would like have the ability to browse to a directory ( c:\test\web.config ) and then load  custom keys from the appSettings section of the selected web.config file.  Example Bind a field within my form to Path=Version

Within the web.config file Version would be identified as:

```
<add key="Version" value="1.0 />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually prefer to use one of the ConfigurationManager methods like this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx

Or there is the old style Xml with XPath:

```
XmlDocument webConfig = new XmlDocument();
webConfig.Load(dllConfigFileName);
XmlNode someNode = webConfig.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/appSettings/add[@key='someKey']");
```

Or the newer LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(configFileFullName);
XElement configurationElement = document.Element("configuration");
XElement appSettingsElement = configurationElement.Element("appSettings");
List<XElement> configSettings = new List<XElement>(appSettingsElement.Descendants("add"));
```

Comment: Thanks Russell. In digging through the site I also found this article while it applies to Win-Forms I have tested it and it is a viable solution adn does not require for the ddocument to be laoded as a regular xml document. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300423/how-to-edit-an-external-web-config-file

Comment: I upped your answer by one for the tip on the XDocument class. I've done a little reading and that is the direction I've taken. Using Linq not only can I prop a colleciton but I can also parse out the specifics of each key!. Thanks again!