# sqlrole manager dynamically add a connection string and or provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, formsauthentication

how can I add a connection string dynamically to role manager?

I'm using asp.net mvc 3 with forms authentication and since this is SAAS app the connection string for each client will change dynamically now I can create new datacontext based on dynamic connection string but is there a way to provide same connection string to role manager?

currently rolemanger is configured using web.config  as follows (example only not actual file)

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add connectionStringName="blahblah">
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1414284.aspx/1) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300423/how-to-edit-an-external-web-config-file) seem to be doing exactly that (If I understand your post correctly).

Basically it's using the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class to modify the connectionstring, or any value for that matter, of the web.config

Hopes this leads you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks but this will not work as I've a webapp and in medium trust web.config can not be modified :(..